# How to decide where the click area should be

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating some thumbnails for my portfolio and wonder if someone can assist me in getting the whole dotted are clickable instead of the "view project" button. Same result for large,medium and small view ports.

I have attached an image and also the code that I am using

Thank you.

See final result here:

[image: Se final result here]

```js
$(function(){$("#navi a").on("click",function(a){a.preventDefault,$("ul.grid").removeClass().addClass("grid").addClass($(this).attr("data-value"))})});
```

```css
.grid figure {
    margin: 0;
    position: relative
}

.grid figure img {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: relative
}

.grid figcaption {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #2c3f52;
    color: #b2b2b2
}

.grid figcaption h4 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #fff
}

.grid figcaption a {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #d5dee8;
    color: #000
}

.cs-style-1 figcaption {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .3s, opacity .3s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform .3s, opacity .3s;
    transition: transform .3s, opacity .3s
}

.cs-style-1 figure:hover figcaption,
.no-touch .cs-style-1 figure:hover figcaption {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate(15px, 15px);
    -moz-transform: translate(15px, 15px);
    -ms-transform: translate(15px, 15px);
    transform: translate(15px, 15px)
}

.cs-style-1 figcaption h4 {
    margin-top: 12%
}

.cs-style-1 figcaption span {
    display: block
}

.cs-style-1 figcaption a {
    margin-top: 20px
}

@media screen and (max-width:31.5em) {
    .grid {
        padding: 10px 10px 100px
    }
    #navi,
    .grid li {
        width: 100%;
        min-width: 300px
    }
}

*,
:after,
:before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box
}
```

```html
<p. class="grid cs-style-1">
<figure>
<img src="https://dribbble.s3.amazonaws.com/users/131151/screenshots/1115960/iosicons_drb2_1x.png" alt="img01" />
<figcaption>
<h4>Changi</h4>
<span>Art Direction</span>
<a href="https://google.com">View project</a>
</figcaption>
</figure>
</p>
```

Comment: Why don't you put all the clickable content into the anchor tag and the "View project" button into a div?

Comment: I did not think about this. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="grid cs-style-1">
    <a href="https://google.com">
        <figure>
            <img src="https://dribbble.s3.amazonaws.com/users/131151/screenshots/1115960/iosicons_drb2_1x.png" alt="img01" />
            <figcaption>
                <h4>Changi</h4>
                <span>Art Direction</span>
                <div class="button">View project</div>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </a>
</div>
```

And in your CSS, you would have to modify this selector `.grid figcaption a` with this:

```
.grid figcaption .button {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #d5dee8;
    color: #000;
    border: none;
}
```